# The predefined dispose function is not available in android studio

Tags: flutter, dispose

i am creating a connection between my flutter application and firebase but when the time came to use the dispose function it is not defined

i've added the package as a library to the flutter and dart

```
dart pub add dispose
```

```
flutter pub add dispose
```

then i import the package in my class using :

```
import 'package:dispose/dispose.dart';
```

but nothing happedned also and the functon still undefined
[the packages that i've added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzp1R.png)

Comment: You haven't used it yet. I don't know why you need a package to close the connection with firebase. Anything I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dispose()` method is only available in Stateful widgets, convert your widget into a Stateful widget and it should let you use it as normal. This is always required if you use Controllers or Listeners to properly dispose them.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to use this instead?

```
@override
void dispose() {
  yourStream.cancel(); //Cancel your subscription here.
  super.dispose();
}
```